# How to emulate min-width in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css

The IE8 documentation says it supports min-width, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

The html I want to be a minimum width is in table cells.

I saw another question here which suggested adding a 1-pixel height div to each cell, with a width setting, but that doesn't work - IE renders it as 18 pixels high, for some reason.

Here is the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
table.keyboard div.key {
    height: 50px;
    font-size:50px;
    border: 5px outset gray;
    min-width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
table.keyboard div.spc {
    height: 1px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: green;
}

table.keyboard td:hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
table.keyboard {
    border: 3px inset blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="body">
<div>Here is some stuff</div>
<table class='keyboard'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class='key'>1</div><div class='spc'></div></td>
            <td><div class='key'>2</div><div class='spc'></div></td>
            <td><div class='key'>3</div><div class='spc'></div></td>
            <td><div class='key'>4</div><div class='spc'></div></td>
            <td><div class='key'>5</div><div class='spc'></div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The "spc" div appears 18 px high!

Of course, if min-width worked, I wouldn't need the div...

```
<table class='keyboard'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class='key'>1</div></td>
            <td><div class='key'>2</div></td>
            <td><div class='key'>3</div></td>
            <td><div class='key'>4</div></td>
            <td><div class='key'>5</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any clues?

Just to make this easier, I have put 3 different versions of [this code on my website](http://www.trumphurst.com/min-width1.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3htmA/

IE8. your code works perfect.

Comment: That's wierd - it works there, but not on my website. I wonder what the difference is?

Comment: so set it :) for example: <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: In case anybody is wondering `DOCTYPE` declaration is needed to avoid "quirks mode": http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

Comment: If a div renders larger than expected, make sure that it has zero padding.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML TABLE spec uses COL to define column widths. See the following spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4

Here's an example of how it's used:
http://www.htmldog.com/guides/htmladvanced/tables/

Min-width on table cells works differently than block-level elements. Table cells are controlled on the column level, not on the individual cell level. If a given cell size increases or decreases, the entire column will be affected, unless explicitly controlled by the  tag.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I want all the table columns to be a minimum width. And I do want the whole column to be affected. Not sure why I would want to introduce col elements at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
table.keyboard .key
{
min-width:60px;
width: expression(this.width < 60 ? 60: true);
}
```

This width expressions is an alternative for min-width, it supposed to be a workaround for older versions of IE.

I think your problem is that your column is determining the width of the element, not the div.

EDIT:

Also check if your browser is not in Compatibility mode.