# minimal width property does not work in internet explorer 8

Tags: html, css

I have a  question,
is min-width supported by Internet Explorer 8? I tried it, and it seems that it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: min-width is supported in IE8 - you'll need to provide more details as to the nature of your problem

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=min

Answer (score 1):

`min-width` is supported by IE7 and higher.

Make sure you aren't emulating older versions of IE by including a Doctype that won't trigger [quirks mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695787/what-is-quirks-mode).

Sources:

- [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/minmaxwh)
- [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width)

Comment: also: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp

Comment: Wouldn't it have been better to just close this question as a dupe? You even [commented on the other question saying the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356525/css-min-width-in-ie6-7-and-8#comment2330766_2356525)

Comment: @Bojangles — Oddly enough, I didn't remember a comment I made over three years ago.

Comment: No, but I assumed you would've looked up any existing posts answering the OP's question before posting this answer

Comment: @Bojangles — Since that question is concerned about IE6, it isn't a dupe anyway.

Comment: It's about IE7 and IE8, too

Comment: @Bojangles — And the answers are mostly concerned with hacking it to work on IE6.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098758/how-to-emulate-min-width-in-ie8):

Did you set `<!DOCTYPE html>` (or some other doctype)? Not doing so causes the browser to operate in quirks mode, which may be causing your problem.